# compactness of probability measures in the weak topology for a non-metrizable compact space

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, duality-theorems, weak-topology

I saw and understood some proofs which showed, that for a compact metric space $X$ the space of probability measures $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with the weak topology ($\mu\mapsto\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu$ is continuous for every $f\in C_b(X,\mathbb{R})$) is compact. Now I read that this is also true for $X$ not being a compact metric space but just a compact Hausdorff-space, but I couldn't find a good proof for this. The proofs which I have found where all like in one line "that is clear because of duality and Riesz-representation stuff" but unfortunately I'm not so familiar with functional analysis and duality. Do you have a good reference, where this is shown in detail?

Comment: The only proof I know of is the one using Banach Alaoglu Theorem. From this theorem the result follows immediately. One can imitate the proof of this theorem and give  a proof based on Tychonoff Theorem.

Comment: I actually don't get how this follows immediately from the Banach Alaoglu Theorem... Could you explain a bit on that?

Comment: The set of all probability measures on $X$ is a closed subset of the closed  unit ball of $C(X)^{*}$. Note that the weak* topology of $C(X)^{*}$ is exactly the topology we are interested in ( what Probabilists call the weak topology).